# Ошибка NullPointerException при заполнении cardview

Tags: android, recyclerview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mCategoriesRecycler;
private LinearLayoutManager mVerticalLinearManager;
private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

    mCategoriesRecycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    mVerticalLinearManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    mCategoriesRecycler.setLayoutManager(mVerticalLinearManager);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    mCategoriesRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.addAll(CategoryItem.getFakeItems());


}

private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<CategoryItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAll(List<CategoryItem> fakeItems){
        int pos =  getItemCount();
        this.items.addAll(fakeItems);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, this.items.size());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.categories_main,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}

private class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView tv;
    private ImageView texture;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.category_title);
        texture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.texture_texture);
    }

    public void bind(CategoryItem categoryItem){
        texture.setImageResource(categoryItem.getTextureResourseId());
        tv.setText(categoryItem.getTitle());

    }
}
```

}

> 10-13 13:54:19.232 20790-20790/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.example.androidnotes, PID: 20790
>                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                          at com.example.androidnotes.MainActivity$RecyclerViewHolder.bind(MainActivity.java:76)
>                                                          at com.example.androidnotes.MainActivity$RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.java:56)
>                                                          at com.example.androidnotes.MainActivity$RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.java:39)

```
public class CategoryItem {
private String mTitle;
private int mTextureResourseId;

public CategoryItem(String title, int textureResourseId) {
    mTitle = title;
    mTextureResourseId = textureResourseId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public int getTextureResourseId() {
    return mTextureResourseId;
}

public static List<CategoryItem> getFakeItems(){
    List<CategoryItem>itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#1",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#2",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#3",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#4",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#5",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#6",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#7",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#8",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    itemList.add(new CategoryItem("#9",R.drawable.stripes_background));
    return itemList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка здесь:

```
public void bind(CategoryItem categoryItem){
    // здесь, texture равно null
    texture.setImageResource(categoryItem.getTextureResourseId());
    tv.setText(categoryItem.getTitle());
}
```

Ищите причину, почему в конструкторе поле не инициализируется как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто, вчитайтесь в свои логи.

```
texture.setImageResource(categoryItem.getTextureResourseId());
```

Скорее всего, именно это и есть 76 строчка вашего `MainActivity.java`?

Значит, ваша `texture` к этому моменту равна `null`, а вы у нее методы вызываете.

Поставьте проверку на `null` и разберитесь, почему в конструкторе она не инициализируется.